# How to change the ReportViewer Background in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

i tried to change the ReportViewer Background from the original color `Gray` to `White` but i cant do that, please help me how to do that?
this is my XAML code:

```
...
<WinFormsHost>
    <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="Viewer" />
</WinFormsHost>
...
```

[image: i want the gray color to be a white color]

Comment: Adding e.g. BackColor="Green" to XAML does not work?

Comment: How did you “tried to change” and why do you think you “cant do that”?

Comment: BackColor="White" by default.  I think what you're seeing is the Print Layout Background Color.  I have not found a setting for changing that.

Comment: @DourHighArch I tried to use all color properties in the code behind and in the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this through `XAML`, but I instantiated my `ReportViewer` inside of my `ViewModel`.

```
WindowsFormsHost wfh = new WindowsFormsHost();
Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer rv = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
wfh.Child = rv;
```

I then set my parameters, `ProcessingMode`, path, etc... for the `ReportViewer` in the `ViewModel` including setting

```
rv.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTanslator.FromHtml("#151515")
```

This successfully changed the background color in the `ReportViewer`
You may need to call `RefreshReport()` before you see any effect.